# Login Statistics SQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a website that does authentication via a login system using a username and password. Every time someone attempts to login, I log the event with username entered, password entered and IP address in a SQL table.

My question: Is it best practise to keep successful and failed attempts in two different tables (Eg. one table for successful logins and one for failed logins), or is it better to save it in one table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would save all in one, and have a column that keeps track of if the login was successful or not. Just make sure you dont save the passwords as plain text.